# В админке Django не отображается название поля

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Начал осваивать Django. Но не получается отобразить из БД название полей, только ссылка на обьект.

Cделал все миграции

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
```

сделал модель

```
from django.db import models

class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Насколько я понимаю, `def __str__` должна возвращать в админку название `title`.

Но в итоге я имею это
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проясните плз как правильно все реализовать :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша функция находится ВНЕ класса модели. Вот исправленный вариант:

```
from django.db import models

class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: ох спасибо, опростоволосился)